# SQL Server jobs fail if I signout the Remote Desktop connection

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis-2012

I have some SSIS jobs running in the production server which we usually take that server by Windows' Remote Desktop Connection to monitor the jobs. The problem in our case is If we sign out the server in remote connection, all the sql server jobs getting failed until we reestablish a remote connection but the jobs work fine if we close the remote connection explicitly by the (x) mark on the Remote Connection interface

Any idea on this issue

Answer (score 0):

Presumably those jobs are being executed under the current users account rather than a system service account ? I suspect the problem is that "signing out" essentially logs the current user off the box, terminating all their current processes, whereas just closing the RDP session does not log them out and so the job continues running.

Comment: Thanks Philliph for your comment, could you help me to proceed to the next step?

Comment: You need to run the SSIS jobs under the LocalSystem or NetworkService windows accounts, not an interactive user account. This is covered in some detail here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/812428/how-to-schedule-ssis-package-to-run-as-something-other-than-sql-agent-service-ac

Comment: But actually I am already using proxy account with administrative credentials of that server to run sql server job agent.

Comment: Then my first comment "Presumably those jobs ..." was an incorrect presumption.