# Error 0x80070005 Access is denied

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have an `SQL Agent Job` called: `Agent1`.

It calls an `SSIS` package: `C:\SSISPackage\ssispackage.dtsx`

The error I get is below:

> Error 0x80070005 Access is denied.

The Windows user that executes the package obviously does not have access to:
`C:\SSISPackage\ssispackage.dtsx`

How do I find out what Windows user is running this package?

Comment: The job is setup with or without proxy user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the user by looking in Services i.e. right click My Computer, then click Manage, then click Services.  There is an SQL server service that is running as a windows user.  That is the windows user I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

When you read sources, you will find that SQL Agent needs a high level of local access and permissions.

Definintely should have a domain account (if in a domain), and be limited as to network resources. Not a domain admin. Probably not a local admin -however, that is often chosen for ease of use. It is best to 'hand craft' an account with just the right type of permissions for Agent to do its job. If a job needs access to resources, then either Agent will need those permissions, or you will set up an Agent Proxy account. Hope these help.

Configuration -Service Accounts, SQL Server or SQL Server Agent service account
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/283811/en-us
http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143691.aspx

Configuration -Service Accounts,Selecting an Account for the SQL Server Agent Service 
http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191543.aspx
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/907557

Please also check the below article. I think this will solve your problem.

[How to schedule SSIS package to run as something other than SQL Agent Service Account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812428/how-to-schedule-ssis-package-to-run-as-something-other-than-sql-agent-service-ac)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186264.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191543.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the third link.  +1.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but my solution was different,
The problem from the logs was accessing the program cache directory `C:\ProgramData\Package Cache`,

```
Error 0x80070005: Failed to secure cache path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\
```

So I changed the permissions for the administrator to gain full access to it and restarted the installation process, and It worked.