# <server\instance> Jobname The job failed. The Job was invoked by User <Domain\Use name>. The last step to run was step 1 (<Stepname>)

Tags: sql-server, ssis

This is our first SSIS package created on `xx.xx.xx.77` for pull data from `xx.xx.xx.56` server and load on share path (server ip `xx.xx.xx.130`) as an Excel file. That path is accessible from both servers. 
SQL Server Agent is configured with `NT Service\SQLAgent$instance` in `xx.xx.xx.77` server.
So we got **Error1**.

Error1:

> Msg: The application-specific permission settings do not grant Local
>   Activation permission for the COM Server application with CLSID
>   {FDC3723D-1588-4BA3-92D4-42C430735D7D} and APPID
>   {83B33982-693D-4824-B42E-7196AE61BB05} to the user NT
>   SERVICE\SQLAgent$instance SID
>   (S-1-5-80-3789775531-3388834719-430539279-2094781381-3838682281) from
>   address LocalHost (Using LRPC) running in the application container
>   Unavailable SID (Unavailable). This security permission can be
>   modified using the Component Services administrative tool.
>
> Log Type: Windows NT  Log Source: System   Source:
>   Microsoft-Windows-DistributedCOM   Categroy: (0)   Event: 10016    User:
>   NT SERVICE\SQLAgent$instance   Computer:

After Google search we go with Proxy user. Now we facing issue (**Error2**) in scheduling that package on `xx.xx.xx.77` server using proxy user.

Error2:

> The job failed. The Job was invoked by
>   User. The last step to run was step 1 ()

FYI: Although same Proxy user has been created on xx.xx.xx.55 server, same error persist while run job on 77 server.

**Reference Links:**

1. [Give access to virtual account](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/70069/giving-file-system-access-to-the-sqlserveragent-virtual-account). But we cant do this due to our privileges is not enough.
2. [Proxy Creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812428/how-to-schedule-ssis-package-to-run-as-something-other-than-sql-agent-service-ac)

We refer more SO Q&A and Google results for SSIS package creation. No one helps. Because our scenario includes two servers. So we need helping hand.

**Edit 1:**

We did this after `Error1`.

`"Launch & Activation Permission" -> click Edit -> Add in the account NT Service\SQLAgent$instance`-> Name Not Found error. Ref: below image. Same error for, add "Service Account" in `Object Type` on below dialogue box.

[image: Name Not Found]

Then we change location from *Domain.com* to *Server Name* in Location as follows:

[image: Location]

Now, `NT Service\SQLAgent$instance` name is found. Then we check `"Local Launch & Local Activation"`. Ref:

[image: Local Permission]

After restart the Service, we got same error. Thats' we go with Proxy User.

[Reference link for Deploy the SSIS package.](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/9069/deploy-and-schedule-an-sql-server-integration-services-ssis-package-step-by-step/)

**EDIT 2**

We move the SSIS project to another `xx.xx.xx.231` server, where SQL Service Agent is configured with Domain user like **backupuser@domain.com**. Now the job is run successfully on scheduled time.

FYI: Another reason of the error is the destination file is may be opened by another user. Here, file is in shard location. When run the job on `xx.xx.xx.231` server, we got same error again. After some cross checking, we found that Excel file is opened by our Team met.

Thanks to All,

Pugal

Comment: The message looks like it is surrounding a COM object referenced by EXCEL. In our shop we don't typically have EXCEL installed on the servers. When we need to import/export files, we use flat files in *.csv format. Are you running this in debug mode from your desktop, or from SQL Agent job, etc.

Comment: On `77` server MS Excel has been installed. I have no idea about _debug mode_. So let me check and update soon. And we will try .csv file format.

Comment: please once again try after check remote launch and remote activation as well.

Comment: No luck @AjeetVerma

Comment: Then sorry bro ,lets wait for someone else responce

Comment: Hmm, Thanks bro.

Comment: @plditallo, If I understand correctly, then this will my answer, I run the SSIS package from SQL Agent job in SSMS. And our reports have multiple sheets. So `.csv` file is not useful.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to provide permission using the below instruction.

1. Click Start -> Run -> Type -> dcomcnfg, expand Component Services -> Computers -> My Computer -> DCOM Config.
2. Click View -> Detail -> Now you will get Application Name and Application ID in right side.
3. Scroll down and find the application ID " " -> Right Click -> Properties and select the Security tab.
4. Click Customize under "Launch & Activation Permission" -> click Edit -> Add in the account NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM and set local launch and local activation.
5. Restart the application Service linked to this Application ID or restart the server and monitor

Comment: Thanks, Ajeet. I have updated the question with image.